# Pass value from php to vue directive

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

This is my laravel blade template file for a modal

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="permissionsModal_{{$role->id}}">
    <!-- modal heading and stuff -->
    <ul class="list-group" >
        <li v-for="permission in roles[].permissions" class="list-group-item">
            <div class="form-check books_category_item">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" :data-roles="roles.name"  class="form-check-input" :value="permission.id"> @{{ permission.name }}
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The $role->id$ is sent by a controller.

In `roles[].permissions`on line 4 I want to insert `{{$role->id}}` inside square brackets.

What would be a good way to pass the value there?

Comment: @YusefMaali I want to pass the value from blade to a vue directive

Comment: Try this roles[{{$role->id}}].permissions

Comment: @GopalKildoliya you think I wouldn't have tried that...It gave `TypeError: Cannot read property 'permissions' of undefined`

Comment: @GopalKildoliya the thing is, when I hard-code the index like `roles[0].permissions` it works like charm

Comment: Have you tried using v-bind? v-bind:id="'permissionsModal_' + $role->id"